# ARKit – eulerAngles of Transform Matrix 4x4

Tags: swift, matrix, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

In my project I have a transform and I want to get the orientation of that transform in `eulersAngles`.

How do I get the `eulerAngles` from a transform of `4`x`4` matrix in Swift language?

I need at least the `Pitch`, I may need the `Yaw` and I might need the `Roll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming mij is matrix element in the i-th row and j-th column.

```
R=atan2(m12, m22)
c2 = sqrt(m00^2 + m01^2)
P = atan2(-m02, c2)
s1 = sin(R), c1 = cos(R)
Y = atan2(s1*m20 - c1*m10, c1*m11-s1*m21)
```

Source:
The math is described in this document really well: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6681/37fa4b875d890f446e689eea1e334bcf6bf6.pdf

As opposed to going to quaternion, there are some corner cases (gimbal lock) you have to worry about that the above solution handles pretty well.

Comment: This has been a great help to me to understand. But one issue still remains, that is C2 is always position, therefore P can be only half of 2*pi. to fix that, just add on line. `c2 = copysignf(c2, m[0][0])` to keep the sign of c2 same as m00.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Eventually, I've managed to find the solution, here is a simple extension with the calculations:

```swift
extension simd_float4x4 {
    var eulerAngles: simd_float3 {
        simd_float3(
            x: asin(-self[2][1]),
            y: atan2(self[2][0], self[2][2]),
            z: atan2(self[0][1], self[1][1])
        )
    }
}
```

I've tested it by comparing default ARFrame.camera.eulerAngles provided by Apple and ARFrmae.camera.transform.eulerAngles calculated with the extension.

Comment: very useful!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> `eulerAngles` instance property is used for node’s orientation, expressed as `pitch`, `yaw`, and `roll` angles in radians.

```
var eulerAngles: SCNVector3 { get set }
```

The order of components is as following:

- **Pitch** (`X` component) is the rotation about the node’s `X`-axis
- **Yaw** (`Y` component) is the rotation about the node’s `Y`-axis
- **Roll** (`Z` component) is the rotation about the node’s `Z`-axis

To use `eulerAngles` instance property is much simpler than using **Rotation `4`x`4` Matrix**. ARKit and SceneKit frameworks use **`4`x`4` Transformation Matrices** to translate, rotate, scale and shear 3D objects. Let's see how they work:

The Identity `4`x`4` Matrix has 16 elements inside:

[image]

Between those sixteen elements there are 6 different shearing coefficients:

```
shear XY
shear XZ
shear YX
shear YZ
shear ZX
shear ZY
```

In Shear Matrix they are as followings:

[image]

Because **there are no `Rotation coefficients` at all** in this Matrix, six `Shear coefficients` along with three `Scale coefficients` allow you rotate 3D objects about `X`, `Y`, and `Z` axis using magical trigonometry (`sin` and `cos`).

Here's an example how to rotate 3D object (CCW) about its `Z` axis using Shear and Scale elements:

[image]

Look at 3 different Rotation patterns (Pitch, Yaw, and Roll) using Shear and Scale elements:

[image]

**Translation `4`x`4` Matrix** looks like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

pj_mukh in his answer didn't say how to convert a transform matrix which I had to start with to a rotation matrix, imallett answered that question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237369/given-this-transformation-matrix-how-do-i-decompose-it-into-translation-rotati)

After you get the rotation matrix you can calculate the rotation angles as pj_mukh said

Comment: If the other thread disappeared, your answer would be of no use for future visitors. Please always include the essential parts of the link in your answer.

Comment: the first 3x3 matrix within the 4x4 transformation matrix is the rotation matrix, so my pseudo code works as-is, no real need to explictly extract the rotation matrix if all you want is the roll/pitch/yaw.